# RepeatRowHeaders not working when subreport rolls over to next page

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report with a couple of header rows that should repeat when the report spans over a page.

I'm aware that [this is not intuitive](http://phil-austin.blogspot.com/2010/02/repeating-table-headers-in-reporting.html), but I can get it to work when the detail rows extend to the next page.

However, my issue is with my subreports.  When they cause the report to extend to the next page, my header rows don't repeat.

I was just wondering if anyone else has experienced this and, if so, what you did to fix.

Below is an image of how the report looks.

[image: Report Tablix Setup]

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not resolved, I have a solution?
have the advanced settings for groups to make some kind of adjustment.